# java hmac/sha512 generation

Tags: java, php, sha256, hmac

I have this php code which generate a **HMAC** (and not a simple message digest):

```
<?php 
$key = "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF";
$binkey = pack("H*", $key); 
echo strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha512', "ABC", $binkey)); 
?>
```

And with `ABC` input its output is:

```
100A6A016A4B21AE120851D51C93B293D95B7D8A44B16ACBEFC2D1C9DF02B6F54FA3C2D6802E52FED5DF8652DDD244788A204682D2D1CE861FDA4E67F2792643
```

And I need to clone it in java.

So here is my current java clone :

```
private String generateHMAC( String datas )
    {

        //                final Charset asciiCs = Charset.forName( "utf-8" );
        Mac mac;
        String result = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] bytesKey = PayboxConstants.KEY.getBytes( );
            final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec( bytesKey, "HmacSHA512" );
            mac = Mac.getInstance( "HmacSHA512" );
            mac.init( secretKey );
            final byte[] macData = mac.doFinal( datas.getBytes( ) );
            byte[] hex = new Hex( ).encode( macData );
            result = new String( hex, "ISO-8859-1" );
        }
        catch ( final NoSuchAlgorithmException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }
        catch ( final InvalidKeyException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
            AppLogService.error( e );
        }

        return result.toUpperCase( );

    }
```

But it does not makes the job because for same input (ABC) its ouput is:

```
AA6492987D7A7AC81109E877315414806F1973CC47B897ECE713171A25A11B279329B1BFF39EA72A5EFB7EDCD71D1F34D5AAC49999A780BD13F019ED99685B80
```

I've tries a lot of other java code but none of them was an exact clone of php version.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply forgot to mimic `pack()`'s behavior in your Java code (whatever you need that for).

Use

```
final SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec( DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(PayboxConstants.KEY), "HmacSHA512" );
```

In your Java Code.

Where `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary()` is from the [JAXB API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseHexBinary%28java.lang.String%29).

Alternatively, if you don't want to include JAXB just for the purpose of converting HEX strings to bytes, you might want to use the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java).

Answer (score -1):

I use this for SHA 512 in Java. It might help:

```
public static String sha512 ( String str )
    {
        try
        {
            return sha512 ( str.getBytes ( "UTF-8" ) );
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
            return "";
        }
    }

public static String sha512 ( byte[] array )
{
    try
    {
        MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance ( "SHA-512" );
        m.update ( array );
        String hash = new BigInteger ( 1, m.digest ( ) ).toString ( 16 );
        while ( hash.length ( ) < 32 )
        {
            hash = "0" + hash;
        }
        return hash;
    }
    catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace ( );
        return "";
    }
}
```

I also remember that there is detailed answer about MD-5 in a post in stackoverflow (just the algorythm is different)

Comment: Actually message digest is different from hmac : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac

Answer (score -1):

try that :

```
private String generateHMAC( String datas )
{
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");

    md.update(datas.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Change this to "UTF-16" if needed
    byte[] digest = md.digest();

    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0;i<digest.length;i++) {
        hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]));
    }

    return  hexString.toString();
}
```

Comment: Actually message digest is different from hmac : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac